# How do I set a a cron to run a pip update in a virtual enviroment daily

Tags: bash, pip, virtualenv, cron

In `crontab -e` would I make a bash script or can I put it all in one line like so

```
00 00 * * * /home/www/ source env/bin/activate pip install --upgrade <package>
```

or would I have to do something along the lines like

update.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/www
source env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade <package>
```

then run the cron like so

```
00 00 * * * bash /path/to/update.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way, but you need to use `cd` in the cron command also:

```
00 00 * * * cd /home/www/ && source env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade <package>
```

The `&&` is there so the command doesn't run if the earlier part did not succeed.  Your script should also stop on the first error, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
cd /home/www
source env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade <package>
```

Since you tagged your question `bash` I took the liberty of ensuring your code actually runs under `bash` and not some other shell.  The `set -e` at the top tells bash to stop on the first error, rather than blindly continuing and perhaps screwing something up.  Every script you write should start with it.